# KeyError: 3 while using dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, if-statement, keyerror

I am trying to calculate number of hydrogen bonds for water in a simulation where I have 3000 molecules of water (1000 oxygen and 2000 hydrogen). So I have written a code for it.

I have a dataframe (`df1`) in which I oxygen atoms at a position which
is a multiple of 3 `(0,3,6,...)` and at other position hydrogen atom and
the x,y,z coordinates of an atom `(xi,yi,zi)`. Now for HB calculation I
need two oxygen atoms whose distance is less than 3.5 i.e. `d1<3.5` and
one angle which I am calculating should be less than 30 degree i.e. `final < pi/6`  .
Everytime my both conditions are satisfied i'm increasing the **`count`
variable by one**. But now here I need to keep two checks that between
two molecules there can be only one hydrogen bond (**flag is used for
it**) and a single molecule can form atmost four HB Bonds (**`record`
dictionary is used for it and in checking this condition error is
coming in the last `if` statement**).

Now I have written the entire logic , but in the ending `if` statement I am getting an error: `KeyError: 3`.

```
import math
count=0
record={}

for i in range(0,3000,3):
  for j in range (i+3,3000,3):
    flag=0
    x1=0
    y1=0
    z1=0
    d1=0
    x1=df1['xi'][i]-df1['xi'][j]
    y1=df1['yi'][i]-df1['yi'][j]
    z1=df1['zi'][i]-df1['zi'][j]
    d1=math.sqrt((x1**2)+(y1**2)+(z1**2))

    if (d1<3.5):
      if(flag==0):
        for k in range(1,3,1):
            x2=0
            y2=0
            z2=0
            d2=0
            x2=df1['xi'][i+k]-df1['xi'][i]
            y2=df1['yi'][i+k]-df1['yi'][i]
            z2=df1['zi'][i+k]-df1['zi'][i]
            d2=math.sqrt((x2**2)+(y2**2)+(z2**2))

            x3=0
            y3=0
            z3=0
            d3=0
            x3=df1['xi'][i+k]-df1['xi'][j]
            y3=df1['yi'][i+k]-df1['yi'][j]
            z3=df1['zi'][i+k]-df1['zi'][j]
            d3=math.sqrt((x3**2)+(y3**2)+(z3**2))

            final=0
            final=math.acos(((d2**2)+(d3**2)-(d1**2))/(2*(d2*d3)))

            if (final<0.523):

              if j not in record:
                record.update({j:1})
              else :
                record[j]=record[j]+1

              if i not in record:
                record.update({i:1})
              else :
                record[i]=record[i]+1

              count=count+1
              flag=1

      if (flag==0):
        for l in range(1,3,1):
            x2=0
            y2=0
            z2=0
            d2=0
            x2=df1['xi'][i]-df1['xi'][j+l]
            y2=df1['yi'][i]-df1['yi'][j+l]
            z2=df1['zi'][i]-df1['zi'][j+l]
            d2=math.sqrt((x2**2)+(y2**2)+(z2**2))

            x3=0
            y3=0
            z3=0
            d3=0
            x3=df1['xi'][j]-df1['xi'][j+l]
            y3=df1['yi'][j]-df1['yi'][j+l]
            z3=df1['zi'][j]-df1['zi'][j+l]
            d3=math.sqrt((x3**2)+(y3**2)+(z3**2))

            final=0
            final=math.acos(((d2**2)+(d3**2)-(d1**2))/(2*(d2*d3)))

            if (final<0.523):

              if j not in record:
                record.update({j:1})
              else :
                record[j]=record[j]+1

              if i not in record:
                record.update({i:1})
              else :
                record[i]=record[i]+1

              count=count+1
              flag=1

    if (record[j]==4 or record[i]==4):
     break

    else:
      continue
```

Answer (score 0):

A `KeyError` is raised when you try to access a key that is not present in the dict. If this is happening in the `if (record[j]==4 or record[i]==4)` line, it means that either `j` or `i` is set to 3, and `record[3]` does not exist.

If `record[3]` should exist, you'll need to figure out why it's not being set. From your code, it looks like a particular value will only be added to the `record` dict if it passes the `if (d1<3.5)` condition. If it does not, then looking up that value will fail.

If it's expected that certain keys will be missing from the dict, then there are a couple of ways to avoid a KeyError:

1. Use `record.get(j)` instead. The method `get(key[, default]`([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)) returns the provided default value, or `None` if a default is not provided, instead of raising a KeyError.
2. If you're not counting on keys being missing entirely, use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for `record`, to initialize the value of a key to 0 if it's missing the first time it's accessed. This would also let you simplify some of your code, so instead of:

```py
record = {}

for j in <...>
    if j not in record:
        record.update({j:1})
    else :
        record[j]=record[j]+1
```

You could do:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

record = defaultdict(int) # calls `int()` for missing keys, which returns 0

for j in <...>
    record[j]+=1
```